# Coin partitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am looking to obtain the partitions of coins that sum to a target amount

So I tried search online, but every single website loves to use this problem to show the benefits of dynamic programming. However, they all only show the number of ways to sum to the target, or the minimum amount of coins.

I am not interested in that, I want the actual partitions. I wrote the following code, it works as intended but is a bit scuffed. The `collected_amount` is incorrect, however, fixing it returns a bunch of duplicates. I "fixed" this by checking the target sum manually before yielding.

Any improvements in algorithm or structure is more than welcome =)

```
from typing import Annotated, Iterable, Optional

Denomination = Annotated[
    int,
    "A positive integer represeting the face value of a coin",
]


def coin_partitions(
    coins: list[Denomination],
    amount: int,
    current_coin: Denomination = -1,
    next_coin_index: int = 0,
    collected: Optional[dict[Denomination, int]] = None,
    collected_amount: int = 0,
) -> Iterable[dict[Denomination, int]]:
    """Yields denominations that sums to a target amount

    Args:
        coins (list[Denomination]): Possible denominations to choose from
        amount (int): The target amount the denominations should sum to
        current_coin (Denomination): The current coin we are iterating over
        coin_index (int): The index of the next current count
        collected (Optional[dict[Denomination, int]]): A dictionary containing the coins obtained so far
        collected_amount (int): The monetary value (sum) of the coins collected so far

    Yields:
        A dictionary reprsenting the denominations and amount to sum to target

    Examples:
        >>> partitions = coin_partitions(coins=[1,3,5], amount=12)
        >>> next(partitions)
        {5: 0, 3: 0, 1: 12}

        Which makes sense since `5 x 0 + 3 x 0 + 1 x 12 = 12`. Similarly
        >>> for partition in partitions:
        ...    print(partition)
        {5: 0, 3: 1, 1: 9}
        {5: 0, 3: 2, 1: 6}
        {5: 0, 3: 3, 1: 3}
        {5: 0, 3: 4, 1: 0}
        {5: 1, 3: 0, 1: 7}
        {5: 1, 3: 1, 1: 4}
        {5: 1, 3: 2, 1: 1}
        {5: 2, 3: 0, 1: 2}

        >>> len(list(coin_partitions(coins=[1,3,5], amount=123)))
        542

        Which is possible to confirm using dynamic programming.
    """
    if collected is None:
        collected = dict()
        coins.sort(reverse=True)
        current_coin = coins[0]
        next_coin_index = 1

    if next_coin_index == len(coins):
        number = (amount - collected_amount) // current_coin
        collected[current_coin] = number
        if sum(coin * number for (coin, number) in collected.items()) == amount:
            yield collected
        return

    for i in range(1 + (amount - collected_amount) // current_coin):
        collected[current_coin] = i
        yield from coin_partitions(
            coins=coins,
            amount=amount,
            current_coin=coins[next_coin_index],
            next_coin_index=next_coin_index + 1,
            collected=collected.copy(),
            collected_amount=collected_amount + i * current_coin,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()

    for partition in coin_partitions([1, 3, 5], amount=12):
        print(partition)
```

Answer (score 1):

The readability is fine. If you cut out the documentation it's about 15 lines long, and short is almost always readable.

Replace `coins.sort` with `sorted(coins)`. Don't modify arrays passed in without copying them first.

Pull out the setup logic and the final denomination into one function. Put the main recursive logic in another. Is the smallest coin always 1? If so, the final denomination logic becomes even simpler.

The performance is probably acceptable for any number of partitions you can reasonably print, though it could be improved. (Dynamic programming or LCMs)